# Techniques / design patterns for postponed delete action from inside of object member function?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, destructor

Say I get into the situation I know that I will want an object deleted - when I am executing code part of a member function of said object. In other words after the function has returned whatever it is to return I want the object to be destructed. Do there exist techniques or design patterns suitable for this situation? I guess trying to call destructor from inside any object is not safe (or even allowed?)

Answers explaining why this is a bad idea and how to do instead will also be welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for RAII?

Comment: Haven't heard of it but will check it out.

Comment: I am trying to understand the problem better. Are you trying to _invalidate_ the object after a member function is called? As in after a member function of an object is called, you want to then destroy the object so it can't be used again? If so, why not just have a 'state' variable in the object that flags the object should no longer be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a self containing object.

This can be implemented using an object that "holds" itself with a strong reference (a strong reference in C++ is called `shared_ptr` which is one of the `smart pointers`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class LengthyOperation {
private:
    // Just a marker, for debugging, to differentiated between objects, and to indicate
    // a released object if illogical value (or if run under Valgrind / AddressSanitizer)
    int i;

    // Privatise the constructor, so it can't be constructed without the static factory method.
    LengthyOperation(): i(0) {}
    LengthyOperation(int i): i(i) {}

    // The "Holder", a reference to "this".
    weak_ptr<LengthyOperation> holder;

public:

    int getId() {
        return i;
    }

    void executeTheOperation() {
        // Strongify the weak "holder" reference
        // So that no-one would release the object without ending of this function
        shared_ptr<LengthyOperation> strongHolder = holder.lock();


        // Simulate a "lengthy" operation, by pausing this thread for 1 second
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        cout << "Operation " << i << " ends" << "\n";

        // Remove the reference to "this" in the holder.
        holder.reset();

        // Now, the "strong" reference which was temporary created (strongHolder)
        // is removed when the scope ends. So that if it is held somewhere
        // else, it will not be released until all other holders release it.
        // Make sure you will NOT need it again here, because the object
        // may be released from memory.
    }

    ~LengthyOperation() {
        cout << "Object with id: " << i << " Will destruct now" << "\n";
    }

    static shared_ptr<LengthyOperation> factory(int i = 0) {
        shared_ptr<LengthyOperation> ret = shared_ptr<LengthyOperation>(new LengthyOperation(i));
        // Make the weak pointer "holder", hold a reference to "this"
        ret->holder = ret;
        return ret;
    }
};

int main() {
    thread thr1([](){
        weak_ptr<LengthyOperation> operation1Weak;
        {
            shared_ptr<LengthyOperation> operation1 = LengthyOperation::factory(3);
            operation1Weak = operation1;
            operation1->executeTheOperation();
            cout << "Still there is a strong reference: it refers to object with id "
                    << operation1->getId() << "\n";
            cout << "Releasing the strong reference" << "\n";
        }
        cout << "No strong reference: it is "
                << (operation1Weak.expired() ? "invalid" : "valid") << "\n";

    });

    // Wait for a relative long time, to give chance for all threads to end
    // One could use "join" as a better approach.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    // Detach the thread to avoid crashes
    thr1.detach();


    thread thr2([](){
        // Make an operation, an execute it directly without putting any strong reference to
        LengthyOperation::factory(5)->executeTheOperation();
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    thr2.detach();

    thread thr3([](){
        // Try to create the object, without executing the operation, to see what
        // weakening the "holder" pointer have done.
        weak_ptr<LengthyOperation> oper = LengthyOperation::factory(1);
        cout << "The weak non-called is " << (oper.expired() ? "expired" : "valid") << "\n";
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    thr3.detach();

    return 0;
}
```

It is like calling "delete" in the `executeTheOperation`, but somewhat safer, by ensuring no other object is needing it.

Also using RAII is better, but this puts the responsibility on the "caller"'s hand. Who instantiated the object, must release it.

(This answer is refined after the comment saying that strong "holder" reference would cause a memory leak if you didn't call the `executeTheOperation`, one should design his code to be self-correcting if its user couldn't call it correctly)

Comment: Ah this was a better explanation. I was just about to try and build one and it seems this shared_ptr was almost exactly what I planned on building.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand the goal of this pattern, but this seems very unsafe from a memory usage standpoint. If the `executeTheOperation()` function is not called for some reason, then you will have a memory leak. Since the object holds a `shared_ptr` reference to itself, that memory will persist even after the `shared_ptr` object in the thread/main function is destroyed. The object's memory will never be accessible again. Straight RAII seems like a much safer choice here. If I am wrong, could you clarify why for me?

Comment: Good point, so we could improve this code by making `weak_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`, and will "strongify" it ONLY during the `executeTheOperation()` using `shared_ptr<LengthyOperation> oper = holder.lock();`

Comment: @user9335240 I agree, and your edits fix the problem. However, this now basically boils down to RAII since the weak_ptr does not have any real effect here. We just need more clarification from mathreadler on their goal

Comment: I think he needs to ensure that his length operator object wouldn't be released externally. He needed his object to be "self-contained". Like a thread internal object for example (after detaching), your functor passed to the thread constructor is removed by C++ STL itself after it ends execution.

Comment: @DanielDay : I see the point, but for my application and class I am quite sure if and only if a certain operator has been called then the previous object which the operator returned from can be destructed. It would save me from having to keep double sets of pointers and calling delete everywhere in the code after such operator calls.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the whole basis of [Resource Acquisition is Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (RAII for short). In short, a handler object will hold and own the memory that you allocated, and this held memory is tied to the lifetime of the holder. That means when the holder object goes away, the resource it is carrying is also properly destroyed.

An example of this would be along the following:

```
class Class { /* definition */ };

int doOperation(/* arguments */) {

  // code

  // this 'smart pointer' contains an object of type Class
  // you create an object of type Class via dynamic allocation and then it is stored within the ptr object
  // this will hold the memory until the end of the function
  std::unique_ptr<Class> ptr = std::make_unique<Class>(/*arguments to pass to the object*/);

  // use ptr
  // assign a return value to returnValue

  return returnValue;
  // as the function ends, the object ptr is automatically destroyed that in turn will 
  // automatically delete the memory of object Class it held
}
```

This use of `std::unique_ptr` is an example of the RAII pattern. Other smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr`, also implement this pattern.